# PHP Access denied after deployment - Logging in

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been developing a simple site locally and am now ready to deploy it to my server - the site works locally. The site reads from a MySql database and is deployed on an Ubuntu server - I have everything installed that I need.

The contents of my page is:

```
    include "Connection.php";
    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    //code continues
```

Content of Connection.php is:

```
<?php
  $user_name = "myuser";
$password = "123456";
$database = "results";
$server = "localhost";
?>
```

Using PhpMyAdmin I have created the "results" database and assigned a user called "myuser" to it with all permissions. 
When I try and navigate to the site then I get the error:

```
Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This makes me think the website is not reading my "Connection.php" file. am I right and how do I fix this? Do I need to change permissions on the Website folder or anything?

Comment: Get ready for the barrage of *"don't use mysql_\*"* comments.  There's no reason why the include shouldn't work.  Are you absolutely sure that user exists for the database on the server-side?

Comment: Is the Connection.php file in the same directory as the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use some debugging...

1. Try using `require()`

   > If PHP interpreter fails to include a file in response to a call of
   >   include() or include_once(), a Warning in generated and execution
   >   continues without that file. Where as, failure to include a file
   >   called by require() or require_once() generates a Fatal Error and
   >   execution stops there.

   And make the script throws an error when it fails to connect, or include the file.
2. Check username and password again. This includes that you even check that the user exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have a valid connection, and attempt database query, php/mysql will try to create connection using "www-data" which is system user which runs apache and php.

Catch error in mysql_connect() and print mysql_error() message, that will help. It might be because of max connections exceeded.

Try hardcoding details in mysql_connect & mysql_select_db functions just to test.

Also check that if Connection.php is getting included. Use "require" instead of include so that it throws error if file missing.